# Form validation returns false, but ajax isn't stopping form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation, ajaxform

I have a multi-part form that begins with a zip code check to verify that the applicant is in my service area.  When a zip code is submitted it runs through the check and does the zip validation properly, as far as I can tell, but will move on to the next part of the form regardless of whether it validates to true or false, provided it passes the `add_zip.length > 4` check.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {  
        $("#add_zip").change(function() 
        {  
            var add_zip = $("#add_zip").val();
            var msgbox = $("#result-msg");

            if(add_zip.length > 4)
            {
                $("#result-msg").html('Checking availability...');

                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "zipcheck.php",  
                    data: {add_zip : add_zip}, 
                    beforeSend: function() { 
                        $("#product_id").html('<option> Loading ...</option>'); 
                    },
                    success: function(msg){  
                        if(msg == 'OK')
                        { 
                            $("#add_zip").removeClass("invalid");
                            $("#enroll_county").prop('disabled', false);
                            msgbox.html('You are in our service area.');
                        }  
                        else {  
                            $("#add_zip").addClass("invalid");
                            $("#enroll_county").prop('disabled', true);
                            msgbox.html(msg);
                            console.log("after msg !== 'OK' finishes");
                        }
                        console.log("after success: function(msg) finishes");  
                    } 
                }); 
            console.log("after ajax function");
            }
            else {
                $("#add_zip").addClass("red");
                $("#enroll_county").prop('disabled', true);
                $("#result-msg").html('<span id="status">Please Enter atleast 5 digits</span>');
            }
        return false;
        });
    });
</SCRIPT>
<form action="" method="POST" class="form-validate" > 
    <h2>Online Enrollment  <span class="step_dcl">(Step 1 of 6)</span></h2>
    <p class="form_area">
        <label id="add_zip-lbl" class="hasTip required" title="" for="add_zip"><span class="star_req">*</span>Please enter your zip code</label>
        <input type="text" name="add_zip" id="add_zip" value="<?=$this->enroll_form['add_zip'] ?>" class="inputbox required">
        <span id="result-msg"></span>                            
    </p>          
    <input type="submit" name="enroll_county" id="enroll_county" class="enroll_btn" value="ENROLL ONLINE">
</form>
```

Also, `msgbox.html(msg);` displays on the page for an instant before the next form part loads when they aren't in my service area, and that it functions perfectly if I click off of the text box or click tab rather than clicking enter after entering the zip.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Update: console.log shows this:

```
enroll.html:567 after success: function(msg) finishes  
enroll.html:551 after msg !== 'OK' finishes  
Navigated to http://localhost/enroll-now/enroll.html  
enroll.html:584 after ajax function
```

I believe this means that the form is still submitting because the ajax request is missing timing somehow?  But I have no idea how I would go about fixing this.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `onsubmit` is only applicable to `<form>` elements

Comment: Add attribute "required" to the input for "add_zip" .  <input type="text" name="add_zip" id="add_zip" value="<?=$this->enroll_form['add_zip'] ?>" class="inputbox required" required>

Comment: Thanks charlietfl, I definitely misplaced the onsubmit tag. It does stop submission with `return false` now.  Unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem though.  T.Shah, the check to make sure there are at least 5 characters will properly stop the form for submitting. My apologies for omitting that part.